# Doctrine id Null после flush

Tags: symfony2, doctrine2, symfony3

Столкнулся с проблемой использования доктрины и понял что не до конца осознаю механизм ее работы. У меня есть несколько сущностей, основная из них - это клиент (компания, фирма, команда) у этого клиента есть пользователи, но все действия идут именно от клиента. Везде работает нормально, но с определенной сущностью транзакций у меня возникает ошибка.
Клиент делает транзакцию, далее я ее получаю и добавляю в оплату. Но когда я записываю транзакцию при помощи merge, flush, у транзакции почему-то пустой id null, хотя в базу все записывается корректно.

```
 public function createConfirmedTransaction(Client $client, PaymentMethod $method, $amount, $wallet, $invoice, $payment_code)
 {
    $status = $this->getStatus('confirmed');

    $transaction = new Transaction();

    $transaction->setClient($client);
    $transaction->setMethod($method);
    $transaction->setAmount($amount);
    $transaction->setWallet($wallet);
    $transaction->setInvoice($invoice);
    $transaction->setPaymentCode($payment_code);
    $transaction->setStatus($status);
    $transaction->setConfirmedAt(new \DateTime());

    $this->entityManager->merge($transaction);
    $this->entityManager->flush();

    return $transaction->getId();
 }
```

Тут мы создали транзакцию и далее я пытаюсь записать ее в оплату.

```
 public function createPayment(Client $client, PaymentMethod $method, Transaction $transaction, $usd)
 {
    $payment = new Payment();

    $payment->setTransaction($transaction);
    $payment->setClient($client);
    $payment->setMethod($method);
    $payment->setAmount($usd);

    $this->entityManager->merge($payment);
    $this->entityManager->flush();
 }
```

Но вылетает ошибка:

> A new entity was found through the relationship 'AppBundle\Entity\Payment#transaction' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity.

Получается, доктрина сделала вставку в базу данных, но не понимает что это сделала, так как не получила id транзакции и не видит ее. Далее я пытался сделать persist транзакции по цепочке до самой последней связи User, когда я делаю на ней persist, доктрина пытается вставить снова user в бд, хотя он там есть.
Почему в этом случае merge не работает, а persist делает повторную вставку пользователя?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из представленного примера не понятны мотивы *повсеместного* использования merge вместо persist, чтобы детально ответить почему наблюдается описанное вами поведение мне надо знать как был получен объект пользователя (видимо этот тот, который `Client $client`) и как был получен объект `Transaction $transaction` в методе `createPayment`.
Почему вставляется новый пользователь при persist - могу предположить, что вы создавали его через `new Client()`, либо брали из кэша, либо как-то ещё, но так или иначе получили его в обход EntityManager-а.

Чтобы самостоятельно разобраться происходящем:

1. Прочтите [документацию описывающую механизм работы метода merge()](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#merging-entities).
2. Изучите каскадные операции в Doctrine. В своё время понять суть их работы помогли ответы на вопросы [Understanding Doctrine Cascade Operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24612664/understanding-doctrine-cascade-operations) и [How to use the cascade option in Doctrine2 to have associated entities automatically persisted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700338/how-to-use-the-cascade-option-in-doctrine2-to-have-associated-entities-automatic), а так же раздел [документации](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations).

Вам надо настроить каскадные операции в ваших объектах и избегать использования merge для новых объектов.

Comment: Вы правы, я по своей глупости при входе в систему, записывал сущность клиента в сессию, чтобы не дергать его в каждом контроллере. Поэтому я не мог использовать persist и использовал merge. А после того, как начал получать null и при merge, отказавшись от затеи с сессиями, все проблемы устранились.